# Generate same XML request tags for methods with different name for soapUI by Java

Tags: java, xml, soap, request, soapui

I want same XML Request tags for different methods

My interface is as follows

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC) 
public interface Services {


@WebMethod public String login(String networkId,String password);


@WebMethod public String loginAS(String networkId,String password);

}
```

soapUI generates following requests

Request 1:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.project.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:login>
         <arg0>?</arg0>
         <arg1>?</arg1>
       </ser:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Request 2:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.project.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:loginAS>
         <arg0>?</arg0>
         <arg1>?</arg1>
      </ser:loginAS>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want my both requests to have same tag ( highlighted)

Desired request :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.project.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      ***<ser:login>***
         <arg0>?</arg0>
         <arg1>?</arg1>
        ***</ser:login>***
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want both the request should have same `**<ser:login>**` tag instead of two different tags `**<ser:login>**` and `**<Ser:loginAS>**`

Comment: `@WebMethod(operationName="login")` doesn't work?

Comment: getting error "operations name must be unique"

Comment: You need to distinguish your 2 methods either by different parameters or different names.

Comment: actually I am the producer of the request. this request has to be consumed by different users. I have to migrate this from dot net to java. in dot net it was working fine (both request were having same tag). cant change the method name or parameter now. any alternative?

Comment: @daniu , any update?

Comment: if are the same, why don´t use just one methot instead of two ?, and add another param to identified.

Comment: @IvanFontalvo, this project is quite old. I got the project to migrate this to Java. If I change the method in any manner then the consumers of this service need to make changes at their end, this is what the project owner does not want. I need to keep the methods name as it is.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggest: use a simple method and add a new param to identify

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC) 
public interface Services {


@WebMethod public String login(String networkId,String password, String newParam);
```

Comment: I can not overload the methods, this is the issue. Can not make any changes in methods' name and parameters.

Comment: have you tried to use a filter, and  process the request whatever you want